# Form in right side of photo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some issues working with bootstrap. I'm a little confused right now. I need to add a form on the right side of a photo in Asp.net MVC. I have a render body on my main page and then in the other view I have this bootstrap code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditarUtilizador", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post,
                                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ImagePath));
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Editar Perfil Pessoal</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <fieldset class="col-md-3">
        @if (Model.ImagePath != null)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ImagePath)" width="150" height="150" />
        }
        else
        {
            <img src="~/StaticImages/default-user-image.png" width="150" height="150" />
        }
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image"
                   type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group" >
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Utilizador, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Utilizador, new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Utilizador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NovaPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NovaPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telemóvel, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Telemóvel, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telemóvel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataNascimento, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataNascimento, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

What I have at the moment is this:

[image: Bootstrap Web Page]

I want to form to appear on the right, but in my case it appears below the image.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<div>` elements are block-level, they will stack on top of one another by default.  Alter the CSS to get what you desire.

Comment: well i tryed to use levels on bootstrap i basicly defined the photo part as a col-md-3 and the form as a col-md-9 and then defined a new row inside, i just have 1 problem, it dont let me close the divs on the bottom :S  i get a parse error

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap Grid Mechanism
You can align content in the following manner

```
@Html.BeginForm(){
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8"> 
        Add the input fields in this column
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        Add the image portion here
     </div>
  </div>
}
```

The maximum value of column in Bootrap grid is 12, you can divide this value into individual columns like I did. You can tweak the col-md-* values according to your preference.

You can learn more about the bootstrap Grid in the following link.
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: You can also stack rows within rows. Everything will work in the same manner as this.